# how do i display all the members with a specific discord role in my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display in my HTML website all the members who have a specific role (for example to display all members that have the "boss" role in my server) but i cant find anything to do it.
I have some code that finds the member counter which i am not sure if its any similar to what i need to do. the code is as follows
(also i need to mention that i am a beginner in JS)

```
<span id="discord-counter"></span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  request.open('GET', 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/792895591255769098/embed.json', true);

                  request.onload = function() {
                  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                      // Success!
                      console.log("Success")
                      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                      document.getElementById("discord-counter").innerHTML = data.members.length;


                  } else {
                      console.log("We reached our target server, but it returned an error")
                      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                  }
                  };

                  request.onerror = function() {
                  // There was a connection error of some sort
                  };

                  request.send();
              </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any `role` attributes in your `members` array.

Comment: yeah i was afraid it didnt. do you know of any other way to get these role attributes?

Comment: No idea how to get the "role" attributes unfortunately - this is a question concerned with the backend. I don't even know what discord is all about.

Answer (score 0):

With "modern" browsers it has become much easier to get server data asynchronously by using `fetch()`. In the following snippet I filtered for members that have a status of "online":

```js
fetch("https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/792895591255769098/embed.json")
 .then(r=>r.json())
 .then(d=>console.log(d.members.filter(e=>e.status=="online")));
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot. however is there a way to get all the members (online and offline) and check their roles?